# How do I check Ubuntu is using my AMD graphics or built-in intel?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have hybrid graphics cards in my laptop.

when I check my systems details it showed

> AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M370 graphics.

- Also my ubuntu 14.04.4 had built-in AMD catylyst control (software).

when I check on terminal by using this command

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
```

it showed

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I am confused how to confirm which are on working.

PS: Please check this image too

[image: enter image description here[1]]

Comment: I believe I have exactly the same computer as yours.. were you able to get the AMD Card working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all graphics adapters are shown as `VGA`.

You can run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` to see all adapters.

To find out which is in use, you can run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`.

Comment: Thanks man!! You save my life. I run this command before ($ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils ) to access this command $ glxinfo | grep OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
lspci -v | grep "VGA controller"
```

gives you more than one line of output, one line for each controller, then, I think this should get the right one:

```
lspci -v | grep -E ' \[VGA controller\]\)$'
```

Comment: both commands showed me just one driver. i.e. AMD

Comment: And if you have two, these two are shown. The regexp is essentially the same and of no use.